# Difference between a Regression and a Regressor

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm confused by these 2 terms.  In sklearn, there are: `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` and `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor`.  Both seem to do similar stuff.  Why are they called differently ?  Are there some underlying implications in using regression and regressor ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this question would have been more appropriate for CrossValidated. There seems to be a related post already on there: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353083/definition-of-regressor

Comment: @JonnDough  Ok. I think I understand a bit better.  Regressor refers to the variable.  Regression refers to the process of predicting.   However, I don't get it - why Logistic is Regression while RandomForest is Regressor.  They both seems to be doing predicting.  What's the subtleties behind these 2 that we call them differently ?

Comment: @JonnDough Or may be I got it. If I'm doing regression, as in Logistic is really doing a regression, then I will call it a Regression. Otherwise, we cannot call it a Regression, and that leaves us with a Regressor as the name ??   I guess why we call it Regressor and not something else.  Regressor is referring to the independent variable, not a process.